# Bootbox with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, bootbox

I know that I can directly add HTML forms via the message, however can I do something like:

```
message: document.getElementById('formContent').innerHTML?
```

Is this my DIV.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Search For Options</label>
                <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="SearchForOptions">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">AND / OR</label>
                <dropdown disabled.bind="readonly" options.bind="core.GetOptionsList()" value.bind="OptionId" selected.bind="OptionId" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button click.trigger="cancelSearch()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
            <button click.trigger="searchOptions()" class="btn btn-info" type="button" disabled.bind="!canSearch">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

core. GetOptionsList() - Aureila

```
import {Core} from 'admin/core';
@inject(Core)
constructor(core){
        this.core = core;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Its pulling the content of the `<div>` however not the values from the DD

```
bootbox.dialog({
    title: "This is a form in a modal.",
    message: jQuery('#search').html(),
    buttons: {
        success: {
            label: "Save",
            className: "btn-success",
            callback: function () {
                //var name = $('#name').val();
                //var answer = $("input[name='awesomeness']:checked").val()
                //Example.show("Hello " + name + ". You've chosen <b>" + answer + "</b>");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

UPDATE

```
addNew(){          
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Search Options",
        message: jQuery('#searchCriteria').html(),
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                label: 'Cancel', 
                className: 'btn btn-default'
            },
            confirm: {
                label: 'Search', 
                className: 'btn-primary btn btn-info', 
                callback: function() {

                    var text = $("#SearchForOptions").val();
                    var dropdown = $("#OptionId").val();

                    alert(text);
                    alert(dropdown);

                    if (!text || !dropdown){ 
                        return false; 
                    } else {
                        this.searchOptions(text, dropdown);
                    }
                } 
            },
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry, I forgot to put this in my original question. dropdown is a custom element, which takes the following:

- options: list of options
- value: value of selected option
- selected: value of selected option

My main issue is can I use aureila i.e. binding elements such as value.bind, or do I need to build my DD manually etc? As it currently looks like I cannot use any binding.

Comment: Given than Bootbox.js is built on Bootstrap.js, and Bootstrap.js is built on jQuery, why would you use `getElementById('someid')` over `$('#someid')`?

Comment: I would also assume that your template is incorrect, just glancing at the cheatsheet (http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet) - `<dropdown>` is not a valid HTML element. I assume you were trying to build a `<select>`?

Comment: Tieson: my second edit of the question shown I didnt use getElementById. dropdown is a custom element.

Comment: Not really familiar with Aurelia. Somewhat looks like you may need to use a template, as noted here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/templating/1.0.0-beta.1.2.7/doc/article/templating-custom-elements. That being said, it seems like you're just duplicating the behavior of a select with your dropdown element. Is that purely a styling decision? If so, I'd recommend binding a select and then applying something like http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ instead.

Comment: No, not just styling, the CE does other things as well, it’s more of a shared DD, so that it is consistence across all developers. The CE works fine normally, my issue isn't that. Its more Bootbox not understanding how to handle Aurelia i.e. the .bind etc. and therefore ignoring certain things. I think I will have to manually create the DD and remove all .bind from the code, just annoying as now this is not going to be consistence with all the other pages. I’ve seen questions around Bootbox and KO so I know it handles certain things

Comment: You can always use either the `.init()` function, or handle the shown event (`.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){ ... })`) if it's a case where Aurelia needs the elements to be visible to do it's thing. I have [an example](https://tiesontrowbridge.com/bootbox/examples.html#bb-custom-dialog) of the former if you need it; the latter requires that you save a reference to the bootbox object, or chain the `on` directly on the dialog function.

Comment: Ill have a look now, thanks :-)